# How should I cache the response from another API?

Tags: java, spring, caching

Right now, I'm making three requests for an external API, and each time, I have to iterate through the responses and find what I have to. How can I cache the response from this external API, that has 3 different end points that I use?

Here's the iteration:

```
      if(list.getData() != null) {
        list.getData().stream().forEach(listItems -> {
        if(items.getAttributes().getItems() != null)
          items.getAttributes().getItems().forEach(listItem -> {
          if(item.getListItems() != null)
            item.getListItems().forEach(k -> {
              if(k.getItems() != null)
              k.getItems().forEach( l -> {
                if (l.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                  description.set(l.getDescription());
                  return;
                }});
              });
            });
          });
      }
```

where "list" is the actual response from the API.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted some of the "iterate through the response and find what I have to" code so we can see what exactly you're doing...

Comment: Added the iterations! Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

try using `@Cachable` which can be used on method or class level

Comment: I've tried but no success. It seems like it's still too slow. Because, if it's caching the response, then it shouldn't take about 6s for the response to come.